# Monetary instrument written to two people which if uncashed is sent to third entity?

Tags: united-states, money-transfer, california

Is there a way this can be achieved? Such as a check written to "Person A or Person B"

I want to send it to Person A in the hopes that Person A takes it or gives it to Person B. Whatever happens I don't want the money, but I want the person denying the money to know that by doing so it has been donated to charity.

Comment: I essentially want to force acceptance of money.

Comment: Denial is possible due to cultural taboo.

Comment: How about you tell us what country's laws you're asking about?

Comment: All members are Americans residing in California.

Answer (score 5):

I think that you could probably structure a trust like this.  The terms would be that the money is in trust for Person A if they claim it by some deadline.  After that it will go to Person B.  This won't be a cheap option though, since you'll probably need an attorney to structure it properly.

Comment: +1 in the US checks are unconditional. Trust would be the only option.